# Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed: In dart

Tags: flutter, dart

soy muy nueva aprendiendo este lenguaje y he estado intentado realizar un calendario que además permita agregar un evento en flutter, este es el código, pero al momento de ejecutar sale error. Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar.
Al parecer hay un detalle en el buttom.
Con respecto a las dependencias en yaml todo funciona bien.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<page2> createState() => _page2State();
}

class _page2State extends State<page2> {
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  Map<String, List> mySelectedEvents = {};

  final titleController = TextEditingController();
  final descpController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = _focusedDay;

    loadPreviousEvents();
  }

  loadPreviousEvents() {
    mySelectedEvents = {
      "2022-09-13": [
        {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-30": [
        {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
      ],
      "2022-09-20": [
        {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
      ]
    };
  }

  List _listOfDayEvents(DateTime dateTime) {
    if (mySelectedEvents[DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime)] != null) {
      return mySelectedEvents[DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dateTime)]!;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  _showAddEventDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text(
          'Add New Event',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        content: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: titleController,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Title',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: descpController,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Add Event'),
            onPressed: () {
              if (titleController.text.isEmpty &&
                  descpController.text.isEmpty) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  const SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Requiere titulo y descrición'),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                  ),
                );
                //Navigator.pop(context);
                return;
              } else {
                print(titleController.text);
                print(descpController.text);

                setState(() {
                  if (mySelectedEvents[
                          DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_selectedDate!)] !=
                      null) {
                    mySelectedEvents[
                            DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_selectedDate!)]
                        ?.add({
                      "eventTitle": titleController.text,
                      "eventDescp": descpController.text,
                    });
                  } else {
                    mySelectedEvents[
                        DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(_selectedDate!)] = [
                      {
                        "eventTitle": titleController.text,
                        "eventDescp": descpController.text,
                      }
                    ];
                  }
                });

                print(
                    "Nuevo registro guardado ${json.encode(mySelectedEvents)}");
                titleController.clear();
                descpController.clear();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                return;
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Event Calendar Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TableCalendar(
            firstDay: DateTime(2022),
            lastDay: DateTime(2023),
            focusedDay: _focusedDay,
            calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
            onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
              if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
                // Call `setState()` when updating the selected day
                setState(() {
                  _selectedDate = selectedDay;
                  _focusedDay = focusedDay;
                });
              }
            },
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
              return isSameDay(_selectedDate, day);
            },
            onFormatChanged: (format) {
              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                // Call `setState()` when updating calendar format
                setState(() {
                  _calendarFormat = format;
                });
              }
            },
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
              // No need to call `setState()` here
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            },
            eventLoader: _listOfDayEvents,
          ),
          ..._listOfDayEvents(_selectedDate!).map(
            (myEvents) => ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(
                Icons.done,
                color: Colors.teal,
              ),
              title: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Text('Event Title:   ${myEvents['eventTitle']}'),
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Description:   ${myEvents['eventDescp']}'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () => _showAddEventDialog(),
        label: const Text('Add Event'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Error en la console:*

Another exception was thrown: Assertion failed:
table_calendar_base.dart:79
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99444 pixels on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta encerrar el `TableCalendar` en un `Expanded`:

```
Expaded(
   child: TableCalendar(
        firstDay: DateTime(2022),
        lastDay: DateTime(2023),
        focusedDay: _focusedDay,
        calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
        onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
          if (!isSameDay(_selectedDate, selectedDay)) {
            // Call `setState()` when updating the selected day
            setState(() {
              _selectedDate = selectedDay;
              _focusedDay = focusedDay;
            });
          }
        },
        selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
          return isSameDay(_selectedDate, day);
        },
        onFormatChanged: (format) {
          if (_calendarFormat != format) {
            // Call `setState()` when updating calendar format
            setState(() {
              _calendarFormat = format;
            });
          }
        },
        onPageChanged: (focusedDay) {
          // No need to call `setState()` here
          _focusedDay = focusedDay;
        },
        eventLoader: _listOfDayEvents,
      ),
)
```